some problem in using the sidebar UI in element-UI
I use the 'Side bar' and the 'Lay out container' to create a WebView by vue3.And I have some problem.

container div class="el-col el-col-12" could not fill out it's father container div class="el-row tac" and a huge gap was created.


Why my side bar do not fill out the page. Only the button area has style.



In the component show, it seems that the style is added on the whole bar and there was no big blank gap.
